# Is the family of equivalence relations on a countable infinite set uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Is the family of equivalence relations on a countable infinite set always an uncountable infinite set?

I can't seem to prove it even though intuitively I think it's true.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE.  Please ensure that your question is fully understandable without the title. The title's purpose is to attract people to your question (and to make it easily searchable). Once it has done that, it's job is done. The question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Recall that equivalence relations are determined by their equivalence classes. Show that there are uncountably many partitions of a countably infinite set into two infinite parts.

Comment: One doesn't need the two parts to be infinite, only that there are uncountably many partitions into two parts.

Comment: Of course, but there are only a countable number of partitions with one part finite, and one part infinite.

Comment: Agreed. Just saying that if one lets in *all* the partitions into two sets, it's already an uncountable number of partitions, with no need to deal with the finite/infinite subset issue separately (and if one does restrict to making both parts infinite, the argument gets more technical).

Comment: @coffeemath: Well, I don't know about more technical. I actually find the argument for this hint to be relatively straightforward. The argument for "all partitions of two parts" usually goes through showing that there are uncountably equivalence classes in the relation "$A\sim B\iff A=B\lor A=\Bbb N\setminus B$". On the other hand the above argument is simpler in that aspect.

Comment: Yes, the details of "modding out" to take care of $A$ and its complement giving the same partition make that approach perhaps even more complex than just showing directly (somehow ?) there are uncountably many partitions into two sets. Can that be done easily without relying on the power set being uncountable?

Comment: I suppose that some diagonal-like argument can be given. Something like taking a $E_n$ to be equivalence relation. Then $2k\mathrel{E}2k+1$ if and only if $2k\not\mathrel{E_k}2k+1$. Something like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11660/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-asaf-karagila)

Comment: Let's not... :-) I hate the chat system.

Comment: OK ignore the chat just sent.

Answer (score 3):

You know the number of subsets of the countable set $S$ is uncountable. If $A$ is a subset of the countable set $S$, there is a unique equivalence relation whose cells are $A$ and the complement of $A$. This gives uncountably many equivalence relations on $S$ which are only a small portion of all the equivalence relations.

Technicality: The partitions associated to a set $A$ and its complement $A'$ are the same, so the map suggested above from subsets of $S$ to equivalence relations is actually a "two-to-one" map, so some argument is required to show that this still produces an uncountable number of distinct equivalence relations.

The "technicality" mentioned here can be easily handled. Select one specific element $a \in S$ and let $A$ be any of the (uncountably many) subsets of $S$ which happen to contain $a$. Then put $B=S \setminus A$ and associate to $A$ the unique equivalence relation with cells $A,B.$ This gives a one-to-one correspondence between subsets $A$ of $S$ for which $a \in A$, and a set of equivalence relations on $S$. Then since there are uncountably many $A$, there are also uncountably many equivalence relations.